# If $u_{2n}$, $u_{2n+1}$, $u_{3n}$ are convergent sequences then $u_n$ is a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The proof is:

Show that if $u_{2n}$, $u_{2n+1}$, $u_{3n}$ are convergent sequences then $u_n$ is a convergent sequence

I don't know where should I start to justify this correctly...

I tried to apply the property that "if $u_{2n}$, $u_{2n+1}$ are convergent than those limits will be the only sublimits of the series", and because of that if $u_{3n}$ is a sublimit then the 3 sublimits are equal and the sequence is convergent... 
But this is not correct I guess because we can have 2 sublimits equal but the other one can be different...

Can someone give a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your question to correct what I assume was a mistake with the subscripts. Please let me know if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Write $L$ and $M$ and for the subsequential limits of the even and odd terms. Without more, there is no reason to conclude that $L = M$.

But now notice that $u_{3n}$ alternates between being an even term and an odd term, and is convergent.

Can you finish from here?